# How to process a django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hey, I want to process one attribute of every object inside one queryset, and after that I want to return the JSON format? How to do with that?

```
results = Sample.objects.filter(user=user)
```

For example, I want to manually add an '*' after user's name field, and then return as JSON format? or remain the queryset type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over a query set, and each element is a single object, so something like:

```
starnames = [ n.username+"*" for n in results]
```

play with it at the Django shell.

JSON format? oh someone else can do that!

Comment: `json.dumps( starnames )` will do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ProcessQuerySet(object):
"""
A control that allow to add extra attributes for each object inside queryset.
"""
def process_queryset(self, queryset):
    """ queryset is a QuerySet or iterable object. """
    return map(self.extra, queryset) # Using map instead list you can save memory.

def extra(self, obj):
    """ Hook method to add extra attributes to each object inside queryset. """
    current_user = self.request.user # You can use `self` to access current view object
    obj.username += '*'
    return obj
```

Usage:

```
class YourView(ProcessQuerySet, AnyDjangoGenericView):
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    return self.process_queryset(queryset)
```

About JSON Response: [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html)